# check an objects array for a certain value

Tags: javascript

```
function weatherCodes(){
let codes = [{sunny:[1001]},{cloudy:[1002,1003]}]
let theCode = 1003
};
```

How can I check my array of objects to find if one of them contains my variable `theCode`

Comment: You use a loop, or the array `forEach` method.  What have you tried?

Comment: Are the only possible properties `sunny` and `cloudy`, or are there others?

Comment: I've used forEach but I get stuck on 

codes.forEach(obj=>{
  //another loop to loop through the array maybe?
}
)

Comment: Yes. I have other objs with properties such as night,fog,snow and so on with arrays that contains there own codes

Comment: Use `.some()` on `codes`. If there are certain keys you want to check, have an array of those and use `.some()` on it. In the callback, use `.includes()`  to determine if the property's array contains the wanted code. If there are not other keys present in the objects aside from ones with codes, you could rather simply iterate over the properties of each object and check them like that. A third approach, similar to the first, would be to have the array of keys to be checked, but iterate over the object's keys and only check those included in the array. Which one to use depends on the context.

Comment: E.g.: `codes.some((obj) => keysToCheck.some((key) => obj[key]?.includes(theCode)))`

Comment: @flyingfox's answer has an approach like the second I referred to. The flattening is great if you simply want to check presence.

Answer (score 2):

A simple reference for you by using `flat()` and `includes()`

```js
function weatherCodes(){
  let codes = [{sunny:[1001]},{cloudy:[1002,1003]}]
  let theCode = 1003
  return codes.some(c => Object.values(c).flat().includes(theCode));
};

console.log(weatherCodes());
```

---

Another option

```js
function weatherCodes(){
  let codes = [{sunny:[1001]},{cloudy:[1002,1003]}]
  let theCode = 1003
  let values = codes.flatMap(c => Object.values(c)).flat()
  return values.includes(theCode)
};

console.log(weatherCodes());
```